# Reading the answer from the query "wmic"

Tags: batch-file, cmd, command-line, command-line-arguments

I can't cope with reading the return code from the command

```
    wmic computersystem where name="%computername%" rename name=aaaaa
```

The point is, I want to notify the error to the person who will be using it without administrator privileges.

How to send "ReturnValue = 5" to errorlevel or goto?

cmd screen
[image: cmd screen]

Comment: test permission level before run wmic command, possibly with `NET SESSION >nul 2>&1` and check errorlevel here

Comment: Regardless of the fact that you didn't initially take the care to post the exact same code as you used in your image, and if you read the usage information for the command you are using, you'll see that the it should be `CALL Rename` not just `Rename`, the WMIC rename method, _(I think from Vista onwards)_, requires that it is Run as administrator. Therefore if your end users are running it without administrator privileges as you've stated, it will always return `5` and be unsuccessful. You will also need to reboot their PC afterwards in order for the change to take effect.

Comment: @user2956477
Many thanks a very good ide. :)

Compo
You are right i will change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to send "ReturnValue = 5" to errorlevel or goto?

```
for /f "skip=2 tokens=2 delims==;" %%a in ('wmic computersystem where name^="%computername%" rename name^=aaaaa 2^>nul') do cmd /c exit %%a
echo %errorlevel%
```

or with `GOTO`:

```
wmic computersystem where name="AKOYA-P4" rename name=aaa |find "ReturnValue = 5;" >nul && goto :label
```

Comment: I was just combining with "tokens" and "delims", but it didn't work out and here we had to add "skip" :) It works as it should now. Thank you